# ORACLE -How are indexes related to COST

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

This question might be weird since my knowledge of sql is limited.

I am trying to optimize a database containing millions of records but i don't seem to  know when there is a performance. I have been playing around with the 'Explain plan' in SQL Developer, but those numbers really don't mean a lot to me.

For instance, I got a table with following columns :

```
ID | Creation_date | End_date | Critical_date | Flag
```

I do run a query on this table looking like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TABLE 
WHERE FLAG = 1
Creation_date < :p_d_one
End_date > : p_d_two
Critical_date < :p_d_three
```

This gives me a COST of 64. So I decided to add indexes.

Now the thing I do not understand is that when I create An index for Creation_date, the cost drops drastically  -> (64 -> 9)

```
CREATE INDEX TABLE_INDEX_CREATION_DATE ON TABLE (Creation_date desc)
```

but when I create and index for the other fields it doesn't change a bit (even though they are also dates).

Any idea if it is still worth including them into my index ? 
Should I still be creating indexes for other queries if they don't have any influence on the cost ?
Is the cost calculated using live stats from the database (Cardinality, ... ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an index over all the fields mentioned in the query (`flag, creation_date, end_date, critical_date, id` in that order) so your query becomes index-only, i.e. the RDBMS does not have to read the table at all, it can get everything it needs from the index.

For a particular query, Oracle will not use more than one index on a given table. Having more than one index is only necessary to support different queries.

Comment: Thx for your answer Erich, I could in deed include all of the fields in my index.
As for the Queries where the cost does not change, do you think it is worth creating a new index for them ( knowing that to many indexes linked to a table isn't good either) ?

Comment: also creating indexes slow down other processes, so I wan't to avoid them if I can.

Comment: Actually the first index is best access path to data and because of it more indexes can't improve the query performance. also creating more indexes has more costs on DML statements.

Comment: @mohsen.b A covering index could make it a bit faster, see  http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index

Comment: @user2933564 You should have those indexes that you need to meet your performance requirements. If a query happens once per day, takes two seconds and that is good enough, creating another index to bring that down to 1 second is probably a bad idea, since every index creates additional costs for inserts, updates and deletes.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller: but it should be check for every side effects. such a index can has performance side effects on other processes